# How to find specific tags for an Intellij Idea color scheme?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I use intellij idea as my IDE and have found a (mostly) suitable color scheme for my purposes.
It is called [naysayer88](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13824-naysayer88).

Although design of most of the color scheme is fine, when code-suggestions pop up as a scroll down menu, the colors of the text and the highlighter overlap, making the text unreadable. Here's an example:
[Color overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjOPl.png)

I'm sure the paid version of Material theme UI has GUI options to change these granular things, but I don't wish to pay for it currently.

Is it possible to fix this by copying the .icls (intellij color scheme config file) and altering values of the desired tags? And if so, which is the specific tag for my requirement? Any documentation regarding this would be appreciated.

Here is the current state of my .icls file:

```xml
<scheme name="naysayer88" version="142" parent_scheme="Darcula">
  <option name="FONT_SCALE" value="1.0" />
  <metaInfo>
    <property name="created">2024-02-19T00:38:46</property>
    <property name="ide">idea</property>
    <property name="ideVersion">2023.3.2.0.0</property>
    <property name="modified">2024-02-19T00:38:54</property>
  </metaInfo>
  <option name="CONSOLE_FONT_NAME" value="Consolas" />
  <option name="CONSOLE_FONT_SIZE" value="14" />
  <option name="CONSOLE_LIGATURES" value="true" />
  <option name="CONSOLE_LINE_SPACING" value="1.2" />
  <colors>
    <option name="ADDED_LINES_COLOR" value="42a87c" />
    <option name="CARET_COLOR" value="86e08f" />
    <option name="CARET_ROW_COLOR" value="" />
    <option name="CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_KEY" value="42327" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_ADDED" value="c3e887" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_COPIED" value="c3e88d" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_DELETED" value="f77669" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_HIJACKED" value="ffcb6b" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_FILESTATUS_DELETED_FROM_FILE_SYSTEM" value="808080" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_FILESTATUS_IGNORED" value="ab7967" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_FILESTATUS_MERGED_WITH_BOTH_CONFLICTS" value="fc9867" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_FILESTATUS_MERGED_WITH_CONFLICTS" value="fc9867" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_FILESTATUS_MERGED_WITH_PROPERTY_CONFLICTS" value="fc9867" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_SVN_FILESTATUS_EXTERNAL" value="72a038" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_SVN_FILESTATUS_OBSTRUCTED" value="727238" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_IDEA_SVN_REPLACED" value="c3e887" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_MERGED" value="c792ea" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_MODIFIED" value="80cbc4" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_NOT_CHANGED_IMMEDIATE" value="80cbc4" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_NOT_CHANGED_RECURSIVE" value="80cbc4" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_OBSOLETE" value="ffcb6b" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_SUPPRESSED" value="546e7a" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_SWITCHED" value="f77669" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_UNKNOWN" value="f77669" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_addedOutside" value="ffcb6b" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_changelistConflict" value="fc9867" />
    <option name="FILESTATUS_modifiedOutside" value="c792ea" />
    <option name="LINE_NUMBERS_COLOR" value="6a7071" />
    <option name="LINE_NUMBER_ON_CARET_ROW_COLOR" value="b59e7a" />
    <option name="MODIFIED_LINES_COLOR" value="6897bb" />
    <option name="SELECTED_TEARLINE_COLOR" value="b59e7a" />
    <option name="SELECTION_BACKGROUND" value="214ff" />
    <option name="SELECTION_FOREGROUND" value="fff9fc" />
    <option name="SEPARATOR_ABOVE_COLOR" value="b59e7a80" />
    <option name="SEPARATOR_BELOW_COLOR" value="b59e7a80" />
    <option name="TEARLINE_COLOR" value="b59e7a55" />
    <option name="TOOLTIP" value="42327" />
    <option name="VISUAL_INDENT_GUIDE" value="b59e7a" />
    <option name="WHITESPACES_MODIFIED_LINES_COLOR" value="b59e7a" />
  </colors>
  <attributes>
    <option name="ANNOTATION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cbe0f5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="ANNOTATION_NAME_ATTRIBUTES" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_METADATA" />
    <option name="BREADCRUMBS_DEFAULT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="ffffff" />
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="b59e7a" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="CLASS_NAME_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FONT_TYPE" value="1" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="CSS.COLOR" baseAttributes="CSS.IDENT" />
    <option name="CSS.IMPORTANT" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_KEYWORD" />
    <option name="CSS.URL" baseAttributes="HTML_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE" />
    <option name="CUSTOM_KEYWORD1_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="9de3c0" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="CUSTOM_KEYWORD2_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="9de3c0" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="CUSTOM_KEYWORD3_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="9de3c0" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="CUSTOM_KEYWORD4_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="9de3c0" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="1" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="CUSTOM_STRING_ATTRIBUTES" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_STRING" />
    <option name="CUSTOM_VALID_STRING_ESCAPE_ATTRIBUTES" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_VALID_STRING_ESCAPE" />
    <option name="DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cbe0f5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_BLOCK_COMMENT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="31b72c" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_BRACES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_BRACKETS">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_COMMA">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_CONSTANT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="70c5bf" />
        <option name="FONT_TYPE" value="2" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_DOC_COMMENT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="31b72c" />
        <option name="FONT_TYPE" value="2" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_DOC_COMMENT_TAG_VALUE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_DOT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_ENTITY">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="6d9cbe" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_IDENTIFIER" baseAttributes="TEXT" />
    <option name="DEFAULT_INSTANCE_FIELD" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_IDENTIFIER" />
    <option name="DEFAULT_INVALID_STRING_ESCAPE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="ff0000" />
        <option name="EFFECT_COLOR" value="ff0000" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="2" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_KEYWORD">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="9de3c0" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_LINE_COMMENT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="31b72c" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_METADATA">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="70c5bf" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_NUMBER">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_OPERATION_SIGN">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_PARAMETER">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cbe0f5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_PARENTHS">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_REASSIGNED_LOCAL_VARIABLE" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_LOCAL_VARIABLE" />
    <option name="DEFAULT_REASSIGNED_PARAMETER">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_SEMICOLON">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_STATIC_FIELD" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_IDENTIFIER" />
    <option name="DEFAULT_STATIC_METHOD" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION" />
    <option name="DEFAULT_STRING">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="ffe66e" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_LANGUAGE_COLOR">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="DEFAULT_VALID_STRING_ESCAPE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="2ca198" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="FOLLOWED_HYPERLINK_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="589df6" />
        <option name="EFFECT_COLOR" value="589df6" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="1" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="GHERKIN_REGEXP_PARAMETER" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_PARAMETER" />
    <option name="HAML_CLASS" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_COMMENT" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_FILTER" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_FILTER_CONTENT" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_ID" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_RUBY_CODE" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_RUBY_START" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_TAG" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HAML_XHTML" baseAttributes="" />
    <option name="HTML_ATTRIBUTE_NAME">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cbe0f5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="HTML_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_STRING" />
    <option name="HTML_ENTITY_REFERENCE" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_ENTITY" />
    <option name="HTML_TAG" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_TAG" />
    <option name="HTML_TAG_NAME">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="HTTP_REQUEST_MESSAGE_BODY">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="HTTP_REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cbe0f5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="HYPERLINK_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="589df6" />
        <option name="EFFECT_COLOR" value="589df6" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="1" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="IDENTIFIER_UNDER_CARET_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="ERROR_STRIPE_COLOR" value="36b13" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="1" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="IMPLICIT_ANONYMOUS_CLASS_PARAMETER_ATTRIBUTES" baseAttributes="CLASS_NAME_ATTRIBUTES" />
    <option name="JSON.PROPERTY_KEY">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="2ca198" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="JSP_DIRECTIVE_NAME" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_KEYWORD" />
    <option name="KOTLIN_LABEL" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_LABEL" />
    <option name="KOTLIN_MUTABLE_VARIABLE">
      <value>
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="1" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="KOTLIN_NAMED_ARGUMENT">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="KOTLIN_SMART_CAST_RECEIVER">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="KOTLIN_SMART_CAST_VALUE">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="KOTLIN_SMART_CONSTANT">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="KOTLIN_TYPE_PARAMETER" baseAttributes="TYPE_PARAMETER_NAME_ATTRIBUTES" />
    <option name="LESS_ATTRIBUTE_NAME">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="LESS_VARIABLE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="6d9cbe" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="List/map to object conversion" baseAttributes="JAVA_NUMBER" />
    <option name="MATCHED_BRACE_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="4f4b41" />
        <option name="FONT_TYPE" value="1" />
        <option name="EFFECT_COLOR" value="42327" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="PROPERTIES.KEY">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="SASS_VARIABLE" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_INSTANCE_FIELD" />
    <option name="SEARCH_RESULT_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="225154" />
        <option name="ERROR_STRIPE_COLOR" value="225154" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="SPEL.BACKGROUND">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="SPY-JS.FUNCTION_SCOPE">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="42327" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="2" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="SPY-JS.PROGRAM_SCOPE">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="42327" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="2" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="Static method access" baseAttributes="STATIC_METHOD_ATTRIBUTES" />
    <option name="Static property reference ID" baseAttributes="STATIC_FINAL_FIELD_ATTRIBUTES" />
    <option name="TEMPLATE_VARIABLE_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="6d9cbe" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="TEXT">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="42327" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="TEXT_SEARCH_RESULT_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="225154" />
        <option name="EFFECT_COLOR" value="3c704b" />
        <option name="ERROR_STRIPE_COLOR" value="225154" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="TODO_DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="11b837" />
        <option name="FONT_TYPE" value="2" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="2" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="TS.TYPE_PARAMETER">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cbe0f5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="VELOCITY_DIRECTIVE">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cccccc" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="VELOCITY_KEYWORD">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="cccccc" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="VELOCITY_REFERENCE" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE" />
    <option name="VELOCITY_SCRIPTING_BACKGROUND">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="42327" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="WARNING_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="EFFECT_COLOR" value="656e46" />
        <option name="ERROR_STRIPE_COLOR" value="be9117" />
        <option name="EFFECT_TYPE" value="5" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="WRITE_SEARCH_RESULT_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="BACKGROUND" value="225154" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="XML_ATTRIBUTE_NAME" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE" />
    <option name="XML_ENTITY_REFERENCE" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_ENTITY" />
    <option name="XML_PROLOGUE" baseAttributes="TEXT" />
    <option name="XML_TAG" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_TAG" />
    <option name="XML_TAG_DATA" baseAttributes="TEXT" />
    <option name="XML_TAG_NAME">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="YAML_ANCHOR" baseAttributes="DEFAULT_IDENTIFIER" />
    <option name="YAML_SCALAR_KEY">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="bdb395" />
      </value>
    </option>
  </attributes>
</scheme>
```

I tried going through the xml file for something obvious but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, this element cannot be changed via regular IDE settings. You can try to contact the author of the custom theme to see if he can fix this or provide an alternative color for this. You can also try changing the source code of the plugin yourself if it is open-source.